# to give print job directly to printer angular 6

Tags: angular, printing, angular6

When it comes to web-based POS (point-of-sales), nothing beats the necessity of printing the bill immediately.However, there are not so many options on how to command the printer directly from web page — particularly when developing with Angular framework.I searched everywhere on web but found nothing.

Is there any third party library or something to accomplish my aim.?

Comment: Hi, just to clarify.  you want to print from an angular web app directly to a printer without any user interaction?    To accomplish printing through the standard approach (with user interaction and standard print dialog) I have found the following resources of interest:  https://codepen.io/mil/pen/WRyzLa  and https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/angular-print-service-290651c721f9.   Besides this you can find a lot of libraries on NPM to (selectively) print items

Comment: I want user to click on print button. That action should print my predifined page without showing any preview or something.

Comment: this: _should print my predifined page without showing any preview_ is not possible via JavaScript only. Think of your Angular App as if it were an audio recording. By itself, the recording cannot produce any sound. It needs something else. Your Angular app cannot display its routes by itself, it needs the browser. Your Angular app cannot print itself, it needs the browser. The browser controls all aspects of producing output from your Angular app (including printing). Your Angular app has no control over that. The print dialog _may_ be able to be bypassed via a browser setting.

Comment: There are more than 100 print outs  printing in a single day at my firm. It will take more than 2 hours to give print from dialog box. There is not any third party library or something to do that (to silently print to default printer)? If not than ,can you suggest me any other solution ?  @RandyCasburn

Comment: @Harshitkyal, having such a library won't solve your problem. Actually, that's not possible for a web app to know about the printer the computer is linked to. Each user will have to define his preferences into his browser. Nothing you can do from the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned by others, there's no easy, one-fits-all, solution to this.

The options I could find fall in the following 3 categories:

1. Browser specific settings

   For some browsers (firefox, chrome) specific settings can be switched on/off or added for silent and/or kiosk mode printing.  As these settings are so diverse and sometimes dependent on the version of browser, I'm not going to try to list them here. you can find the methods online for the browser you use under silent printing.
2. Browser specific plug-ins

   Some plugins can be found too, but they might just do the same things as toggling the settings in the background as number 1
3. Custom

   One very specific/involved/"hands-on" option that I have found is to work through a 
   service whith custom designed url/file type handlers.  you can find the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQMD4Pb7jzY

As you already mentioned.  choices are not optimal, but maybe there's something you could work out from these.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood that you need a solution to print the HTML page, this third-party library ([**ngx-print**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print)) might be helpful to you.

Once you install and import **NgxPrintModule** module, tag your wanted-to-print section by an *id* attribute, then link that *id* to a directive parameter in your button: (like this)

```
<!--
   1)- Add an ID here
 -->
<div id="print-section"> 
  <!--Your html stuff that you want to print-->
</div>

 <!--
   2)- Add the directive name in your button (ngxPrint),
   3)- Affect your ID to printSectionId
 -->
<button printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

This will help you print HTML part directly from the angular 7 code.

Comment: I want to give print to my default printer. Is it possible from this ?

Comment: Hi @Harshitkyal, javascript can't bypass the browser print confirmation window.
This is for security reasons. Otherwise, any website could print stuff to your printer without warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish POS printing with an angular app by completely bypassing the browser for printing.  I setup a websocket that the printer connects to and listens for new receipts to print. When a new receipt is made in the website, the backend creates a new receipt and sends it out on the websocket.

Comment: so only special type of printer which has direct connection with backend can only do this?

Comment: I was able to use any printer but I had to have a special host for the printer that connected to the backend. In my case, I used a raspberry pi.  Otherwise, there is no way to bypass the print dialog

Comment: Yeah, I have.  I looked into it but didn't use it for some issue.  I was using a tablet and wanted to not have a print dialog.  I'm sure you could use a server function to fire it off to the printer.  I also worry about free google services like cloud print will one day be shutdown. I think cloud print is unsupported come the end of 2020

Comment: do you have sample for this app?